# Use the graph of f to find the limit

Tags: calculus

How can I use the graph of f to find the limit?

[image]

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^−}f(x)$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1^+}f (x)$

I am not sure where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the graph!

When you come from numbers smaller than 1, the function gets bigger and bigger, so it goes to $\infty$. Therefore we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}} = +\infty$.

When you come from numbers smaller than 1, the function gets smaller and smaller, so it goes to $-\infty$. Therefore we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}} = -\infty$.

Also, make sure to get the right notation. The post has been edited, but it wasn't correct before the edit.

Answer (score -1):

Just looking at the graph we have:
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=+\infty, \quad \lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=-\infty.
$$